# How to create a Karaf features file from my local bundles?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I want to understand how to create a features xml and install in Karaf to auto start a bunch of my custom bundles.

I'm using Maven and have two modules in my project:

- core.api
- core.api-impl

When I run `mvn clean install` I see the following output:

```
[INFO] framework .......................................... SUCCESS [  0.340 s]
[INFO] deqa.core.api ...................................... SUCCESS [  1.555 s]
[INFO] core.api-impl ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.144 s]
```

I see that the jars get placed into my ~/.m2, but not sure how this would properly translate into a feature XML file.

```
/.m2/repository/com/deqa/core.api-impl/1.0-SNAPSHOT/core.api-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Ideally, I'm going to have several bundles that represent one core feature for me, and I want to be able to easily build up these features and have them auto start all my bundles.

I started building a features file in the root in `karaf-config` dir with a `karaf-features.xml` file:

```
<features
        name="osgi-demo-features"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.3.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.3.0
    http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.3.0">

    <!-- Additional repositories from which bundles are loaded -->
    <repository>mvn:org.apache.cxf.dosgi/cxf-dosgi/1.7.0/xml/features</repository>

    <feature
            name="DEQA-CORE"
            version="1.0.0"
            description="Feature for baseline DEQA API functionality"
            install="auto">

        <!-- Felix dependency manager -->
        <bundle start="true" start-level="10">
            mvn:com.deqa/deqa.core.framework.commons/1.0-SNAPSHOT
        </bundle>
    </feature>

</features>
```

Not quite sure what to do at this point or if I am fully understanding this concept.

Comment: Looks good so far. What problem do you face? One hint. Leave out the unnecessary stuff like install=auto, start-level or start=true. Only use these if you know what they do.

Comment: Ultimately, I'm wondering how to get the coordinates to be correct. Seems off to me and I'm not getting a proper autocomplete from my IDE. Do I need a specific MVN plugin for this to be built correctly?

Comment: You simply use the mvn urls with mvn:groupid/artifactid/version

Comment: See this for an example: https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/blob/master/tasklist/tasklist-features/src/main/resources/features.xml

Comment: I seem to have the mvn coordinates correct and they reside in the root/karaf-config. I'm just not sure what happens now. Does it need to exist in a MVN module or a standard directory? When I run my project, the features file isn't picked up. I'm wondering what it takes to be able to run the feature repo add command with my custom features file

Comment: At this point, I added the repo using feature:repo-add file:XML path and see it in Karaf. I attempt to install the associated feature but get the following : Error executing command: Error:
 Unable to create resource for bundle mvn:com.deqa/deqa.core.api/1.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168425/discussion-between-ryan-hack-and-christian-schneider).